# Cannot get updated DB Data with PYODBC and FLASK Python

Tags: python, flask, pyodbc

I seem to be having issues querying a PYODBC connection from a Flask connection in Python. Initially I had the entire file using the same connection, but noticed when you would hit the URL for the Get request it would not return the most recent data. So i adjusted script to start and kill connection each time a get request is initiated this returns the same non updated data. I do notice that occasionally it will update the data but most times it will not.

Please assist better clarify this process.

```
def getChg(s, cursor, arr):
getIncResolved = "SELECT COUNT(incident.number) FROM SCHEMA.OAUSER.incident incident WHERE incident.dv_resolved_by = '" + str(s) + "' AND incident.resolved_at BETWEEN '" + str(past) + "' AND '" + str(current) + "' AND incident.dv_opened_by != '" + str(s) + "';"
getTaskResolved = "SELECT COUNT(sc_task.number) FROM SCHEMA.OAUSER.sc_task sc_task WHERE sc_task.dv_closed_by = '" + str(s) + "' AND sc_task.closed_at BETWEEN '" + str(past) + "' AND '" + str(current) + "' AND sc_task.dv_opened_by != '" + str(s) + "';"
getCallStarted = "SELECT COUNT(new_call.number) FROM SCHEMA.OAUSER.new_call new_call WHERE  new_call.opened_at BETWEEN '" + str(past) + "' AND '" + str(current) + "' AND new_call.dv_opened_by = '" + str(s) + "';"
i = 0
t = 0
c = 0
cursor.execute(getIncResolved)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    i = row[0]

cursor.execute(getTaskResolved)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    t = row[0]
cursor.execute(getCallStarted)
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    c = row[0]
if c > -1:
    test = {'Agent': str(s), 'Calls': c, 'Inc': i, 'Task': t}
    arr.append(test)



@app.route('/data',methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def api_root():  cnxn=pyodbc.connect('DSN=ServiceNow;Uid=ServiceOps;Pwd=********;',autocommit=True)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
data = []
staffjson = request.get_json(force=True)
staff = staffjson['users']
print(staff)
del data[:]
for s in staff:
    getChg(s, cursor, data)
print(data)
cnxn.close()
return json.dumps(data)
```

Comment: Thanks for that. This ODBC Driver only allows SELECT's. There will be no writing to the database.  I will adjust to a parameterized query just for better habbit.

Answer (score 0):

The Current variable was only being created at the initial start of the script. Therefore once it was loaded it never updated to the current time.

Created variable at each request now and is working as i expected.